# Saving/ exporting a selection of residues from ChimeraX to a separate file (on Windows)?

Tags: pymol, chimerax

I have a selection of various loops in a protein that are discontiguous (eg. 103-107, 127-130, etc.) that I would like to save/ export/ print somewhere like an external txt or log file, so that basically I have list like the below. I can't seem find an option in the GUI or any online code that will do it.

pos
103
104
105
106
107
127
128
129
130

Comment: https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/menu.html#select ---> you can select Coil – amino acid residues not in helix or strand